# Show that there exists a connected component $C$ s.t. $f^{(n)}(C)\subseteq C$ where $f$ is continous

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was studying a published paper about local contractive mappings on metric spaces http://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/prepF/124.FandPP.pdf. On the prove of a theorem there was used the fact below:

> Let $C_1, C_2,...,C_n$ be connected components of the metric space $(X,d)$. Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous function (in the paper $f$ is a uniform localy contractive (ULC), but I think for my question continuity is enought). Show that there exists $C\in \{C_1, C_2,...,C_n\}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $f^{(n)}(C)\subseteq C.$

Attempt: Since $f$ is continuous and $C_1$ is connected, there exists $C\in \{C_1, C_2,...,C_n\}$ and $i,k\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $f^{(i)}(C_1)\subseteq C$ and $f^{(i+k)}(C_1)\subseteq C$. In the paper this fact is used to show that $f^{(k)}(C)\subseteq C$. How can we show that?

Comment: One thing that confused me about both this question and the answers is that n is used with at least two different meanings. Otherwise, cool question.

Comment: @ZachBoyd : you are right I edited the answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: $C_1, \dots, C_n$ are *all* the components of $X$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, X has a finite number of components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said there is an index $i_1$ with $f(C_1) \subset C_{i_1}$, and there is $i_2$ with $f(C_{i_1}) \subset C_{i_2}$, and so one.

We have two possibilities :

- This sequence is stationnary (i.e there is an index $j$ with $f(C_j) \subset C_j$) and we are done.
- There is a cycle $(j_1, \dots, j_m)$ with $f(C_{j_k}) \subset C_{j_{k+1}}$, in particular $f^{m}(C_{j_1}) \subset C_{j_1}$.

So indeed there is such a component.